# Passing an array of unknown size to class constructor

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to write a function CycleManager which can hold an array of Cycles. My problem is that I want this class to be able to hold a variable amount of cycles. This is what I came up with, but it's not working.

Cycle.h

```
class Cycle
{
public:
    Cycle(std::string name) : name(name) {}

private:
    std::string name;
};
```

CycleManager.h

```
#include "Cycle.h"

class CycleManager
{
public:
    CycleManager(Cycle (&cycles)[]);
    void getCycles();

private:
    int currentCycle;
    int numberOfCycles;
    Cycle (&cycles)[];
};
```

CycleManager.cpp

```
CycleManager::CycleManager(Cycle (&cycles)[]) : cycles(cycles), currentCycle(0)
{
    numberOfCycles = sizeof(*cycles) / sizeof(Cycle);
}

void CycleManager::getCycles()
{
    // Serial.println(this->numberOfCycles);
    std::cout << this->numberOfCycles << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
Cycle cycles[] = {Cycle("Cycle 1"), Cycle("Cycle 2"), Cycle("Cycle 3")};
CycleManager cycleManager(cycles);

int main()
{
    cycleManager.getCycles();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is using arrays instead of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) required?

Comment: Use `std::vector`?

Comment: I'm working on an embedded system so can't use vectors.

Comment: Do you know what the largest size array you could possibly need?  Use that upper limit to declare the array size, and just use less of the array's maximum capacity.

Comment: @AnoopRana You closed to soon, the question is relevant since OP is on an embedded system and he cannot use std::vector.

Comment: I've had to work in an embedded system that had no heap, so I couldn't use `std::vector`.

Comment: Probably you can still use std::array, it is a bit more friendly to use when you want to pass it around and/or return arrays from functions. @OP , Next time be a bit more clear about being in an embedded system, rules change a bit then :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Note that here the OP says " it's not working." It is not clear, what do they mean by not working. Does it mean not compiling or runtime error or something else. This question is not clear at all. Additionally the dupes already explain that from C++20 we can pass array of known bound as argument to parameter of type reference to array of unknown bound. Moreover which version of C++ is the OP using. This question is lacking information and so(in its current state) is a duplicate of the linked dupes.

Comment: to get a limited-sized stack-based vector use `boost::container::static_vector`. See [Variable-length std::array like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850093/995714)

Comment: and instead of `Cycle cycles[] = {Cycle("Cycle 1"), ...};` you should use [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which provides the size, similar to how standard containers like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) receive a variable list of inputs

Answer (score 1):

```
Cycle cycles[] = {Cycle("Cycle 1"), Cycle("Cycle 2"), Cycle("Cycle 3")};
CycleManager cycleManager(cycles);
```

At this point you know the size of the array. So why not

```
CycleManager cycleManager(cycles, size);
```

Adjust constructor appropriately

```
CycleManager(Cycle* cycles, size_t n):cycles(cycles), numberOfCycles(n)...
```