# A C++ container similar to dynamic array?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, containers, dynamic-arrays

In [this set of slides](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp.pdf) the author highly recommends to avoid pointers in C++ programs. Specially in slide 6, using vectors are suggested instead of dynamic arrays. While I believe vectors are much safer to use, for example they avoid memory leaks when an exception happens, they have extra memory overhead. [This post](http://www.frogatto.com/?p=26) says that vectors can consume up to twice the size of existing elements in the vector. Unfortunately, this feature causes my program to abort in my system with limited amount of available memory.

Is there a C++ container similar to dynamic arrays, getting the fixed (or rarely changing) number of elements in runtime, and provide the same safety as containers? The closest thing I could find ([here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) was `array` which required compile-time specified size provided in `template`.

Comment: *fixed (or rarely changing)* there's a pretty large difference between the two implementation-wise, so which one will it be? Have you tried http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/ ? Unfortunately for you http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray was left out

Comment: @stijn Assume only *fixed*, but known in runtime. Although the description of `shrink_to_fit` says "The request is non-binding, and the container implementation is free to optimize otherwise and leave the vector with a capacity greater than its size", it seems to be useful. About `dynarray`, do they mean it's not going to be supported anymore??

Comment: re: *container implementation* indeed depends, my suggestion is to check your lib's implementation to see what it does. If it always shrinks it should be useful enough. re: dynarray: it's put in a seperate TR which means it's just postponed I think. But look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303902/any-alternative-to-stddynarray-presently-available

Comment: @Farzad: It means it will not be in C++14 but should be in a separate (upcoming) Technical Specification. See the status here (http://isocpp.org/std/status).

Comment: The answer here really depends on what your constraints and goals are. Growing a `vector` with `push_back`, without any further code, will potentially use 3x the memory of the current content (2x for the new vector, and 1x for the current content, which will get freed once the copy has been made). A way to avoid this would be to rely on resize, although the behaviour is not GUARANTEED to give exactly that number of elements, it is not typically giving 2x the size. `shrink_to_fit` is also useful if elements are removed...

Comment: Have you considered `std::deque`? http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can use the array specialization of `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[5]);
```

This will safely manage the memory for you.

Comment: Do people actually use `unique_ptr` like this? Sure it takes care of the deallocating the memory, but you still have to carry around the size in a separate variable. Very ugly, imo.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: It is an improvement over managing a raw pointer, which was the initial motivation presented in the question. Perhaps the problem could be resolved by providing a custom allocator to `vector`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the fixed size, just calling `reserve(n)` on the `vector` should do the trick.  While it isn't guaranteed not to use more space, I don't know of any implementations that don't just allocate space for exactly that number of elements (assuming it is greater than the current `capacity()`, of course).

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Don't use a unique_ptr

Comment: It looks like the response to [n4524](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4524.pdf) at the Kona meeting was favorable, so we might get the guarantee.