# How to Deep Copy Values of Vector Pointer (Not just the pointer)?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, copy

I've an operator and function which goal is to copy the values of the vector pointer to a vector. I've read that as long it's a vector pointer, deep copying methods would only copy its pointer, not its value. I'm wondering how to copy it's values over instead. *(The vector is a member of CObject class)*

Operator function:

```
void CObject::operator=(CObject& rhs)
{
    this->ClearObject();   //Object will be cleared first
    // How to perform the deep copy below?
    copy(rhs.m_Vector.begin(), rhs.m_Vector.end(), back_inserter(this->m_Vector));
}
```

Declared as -> `void operator=(CObject& rhs);`

Example application of operator function *(Performed in another class)*:

```
CObject* m_pObjectOne;
CObject  m_ObjectTwo;

m_ObjectTwo = m_pObjectOne;
```

*(Therefore, when m_pObjectOne is deleted in its class destructor, m_ObjectTwo loses its value)*

Vector & others:

```
struct OBJECT_ITEM
{
    char  m_chType;
    UINT  m_nDataByte;
    BYTE* m_pData;
    CString m_strRecipeTag;
}

std::vector<OBJECT_ITEM> m_Vector;
```

I've also tried other deep copy methods like `push_back()` & `assign()` but it gives me the same result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can `m_ObjectTwo = m_pObjectOne` really be compiled? The `operator=` function you provided does not accept a `CObject *` rhs.

Comment: @Sprite yes it's compilable. Hmm I'm wondering if it's because I've simplified it. m_pObjectOne & m_ObjectTwo have arrays on my end. But it's still similar. The declaration is also done in header.

Comment: @Han What does the vector hold exactly that you are trying to copy? Please provide more details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've edited the vector contents into the questions, do take a look.

Comment: @Han I assume the issue is with the `OBJECT_ITEM::m_pData` field? If you update `OBJECT_ITEM` to implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) properly to copy data from one `OBJECT_ITEM` to another, your `std::copy()` code will then work as-is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau However I'm able to view m_pData after being copied over while debugging. The value only disappears after pointer is destroyed.

Comment: @Han that doesn’t change what I said. Your code is currently shallow-copying `m_pData`, which won’t work if each `OBJECT_ITEM` is expected to have its own data allocated. `OBJECT_ITEM` should have a destructor, a copy constructor, and a copy assignment operator (and in C++11 and later, a move constructor, and a move assignment operator), so that each `OBJECT_ITEM` fully manages its own data.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau I now understand what you are saying. I'll try it out this way.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### Strive for the "rule of zero".

> How to Deep Copy Values of Vector Pointer (Not just the pointer)?

Basically - don't. You should strive to follow the [rule of zero](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/04/23/the-rule-of-zero-zero-constructor-zero-calorie/): Unless otherwise necessary, set things up so that the default constructors, assignment operators and destructors do what they should.

In your case: Suppose you let `CObject` use its default (copy) assignment operator. That means, that `rhs.m_Vector` will be assigned to `lhs.m_Vector`. And vector assignment means that individual members of the vector are assigned to their corresponding members.

The way you wrote your vector, that won't do what you want: You wrote you want to avoid the case of "when `m_pObjectOne` is deleted in its class destructor, `m_ObjectTwo` loses its value)". Well, since you're willing to hold copies of the objects, consider something like the following:

```
struct OBJECT_ITEM
{
    char  m_chType;
    UINT  m_nDataByte;
    MyContainer m_upData;
    CString m_strRecipeTag;
}
```

And choose or write `MyContainer` to suit your needs. It could just be an `std::vector<BYTE>`; or if you don't want the size to change after construction, use a [dynarray](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/boi2016/doc/cppreference/reference/en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray.html) (not in the standard library these days; [here's an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306005/1593077)); etc. And your chosen container will actually get properly copied when you copy an `OBJECT_ITEM`. Finally, don't hold pointers to `OBJECT_ITEM`'s - just hold actual `OBJECT_ITEM`'s (which it seems you were already doing?)

And there, now you can no longer have dangling pointers - with no custom constructors, assignment operators or anything else like that.